# Too many child with fork()

Tags: c, fork

The code :

```
for ( ii = 0; ii < 24; ++ii) {

    switch (fork()) {

        case -1 : {
                printf("\n\nproblem with fork() !!! \n\n");
                exit(0);
                };

        case 0 : {
                WriteOnShared_Mem(ii);
                }break;
        default : {
                ChildPidTab[ii] = p;
                usleep(50000);
                ReadShared_MemMp(nbSect, 24,ChildPidTab);
                };
    }
}
```

My problem is that i get too many child (nbenfant = 24), i got much more than 24 :/

This is my 3rd post today here but still not solved :(

Thanks

Comment: Please use English in your code (identifiers, strings, comments)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read *carefully* the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page. Read that page several times, it is hard to understand. Read also the wikipage on [fork (system call)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) and on [processes (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).

<sup>Please understand -and that takes time- that `fork` is returning *simultaneously twice* on success: once in the parent and once in the child</sup>

The `fork` syscall can fail (and then returns -1) for a number of reasons. On failure of `fork` please use `perror` or some other way to show the `errno`. And you should always keep the result of `fork`. So code

```
for (ii = 0; ii < 24; ++ii) {
 fflush(NULL);
 pid_t p = fork();
 switch (p) {
    case -1 : // fork failed 
            printf("\n\nproblem with fork() in pid %d error %s!!! \n\n",
                   (int) getpid(), strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
    case 0: // child process
            WriteOnShared_Mem(ii);
            ii = MAX_INT; // to stop the for loop
            break;
    default: // parent process
            ChildPidTab[ii] = p;
            /// etc.... some synchronization is needed
            break;
    }
```

In particular, `fork` can fail because

> ```
>    EAGAIN fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the
>           parent's page tables and allocate a task structure for 
>           the child.
>    EAGAIN It was not possible to create a new process because the
>           caller's RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit was encountered.  To
>           exceed this limit, the process must have either the
>           CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.
>    ENOMEM fork() failed to allocate the necessary kernel structures
>           because memory is tight.
> ```

If you want to be able to fork more processes, try to:

- increase the `RLIMIT_NPROC` resource limit with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (which might be called by system facilities, so look also into `/etc/pam.d/login` etc
- lower the resources required by the `fork`-ing program. In particular, lower the heap memory requirements
- increase some system resources, like perhaps swap. You could `swapon` some temporary file for testing.

As [Joachim Pileborg replied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18549439/841108) you should avoid forking too much (the forked process continues the loop so is also forking again).

Don't forget that `stdio` routines are buffered. Use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) appropriately.

I suggest reading the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book (available online) which has a full chapter explaining process handling on Linux.

BTW, check with `ps` or `top` or `pstree` how many processes you have (and with the `free` command how much memory is used, but read http://linuxatemyram.com/ before complaining). It could happen that your particular system is not able to fork more than 24 times your particular program (because of lack of resources)

Study also the source code of simple shells (like `sash`) and use `strace -f` (e.g. on some shell, or on your program) to understand more what syscalls are done. Also learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: I just want my 24 child but they need to be running at the same time.

Comment: "forking too much" how i just did one fork :(

Comment: ok thanks for the correction for the fork() error but i can't check it because there is no error when i do the fork() -_-

Comment: Please take several hours to read tutorials and linked resources. You have some fundamental misunderstandings. You need to learn a lot more. And add more `printf` and `fflush` calls for debugging purposes.

Comment: yes sir i know, I'm still a student and learning each day but when i don't get something i come ask to others like you :)

Comment: But asking is less efficient than learning, and learning requires time (and reading and experimenting).

Answer (score 1):

It's because each child continues with the loop and so in turn fork their own children. When the children are done, you should either return from the main function or call `exit`.

Comment: yes the problem is that i can't use the exit() bcz it will kill the children and I need 24 child running at once :/ Those r the instruction.

Comment: @shubha The `exit` call just exits the *current* process, not its parent or sibling processes.

Comment: yes, if I do exit on the children it will kill them but i don't want that i just want 24 children running at the same time. Is that possible ?

Comment: @shubha You really can't guarantee that with a multitasking system. What do you want to happen if the function you call `WriteOnShared_Mem`) returns before all child processes has been created? It seem you want some synchronization to make sure all processes are running before you continue with that function?

Comment: yes thats why i use semaphore, when i do the WriteOnShared_Mem() i do +1 on the semaphore value, and in the function ReadShared_MemMp of the parent, this one will be activected only if semaphore value = 24 (the number of children who wrote on the shared Memory)

Comment: @shubha Ok, then the problem is when the `WriteOnShared_Mem` function *returns*, in that the children continue the loop! After the function returns you *must* exit from the process.

Comment: aaah yes i know that i need to stop the child but i can't use the exit() bcz it will kill the child and i won't have concurrency anymore (it is asked on the instruction). So i tried to use break and pause but didn't work :(

Comment: @shubha When the child is done, it's done. Why do want to keep the child process running idle even after it's done? If you want to call the function multiple times then have a loop in that specific case, and when the child is done then call `exit`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: ok I didn't explain clearly sorry, so the main point of this program is to integrated concurrency/synchronisation. So i need to have multiple process running at the samme time :/ And i could use the thread but i already started with the fork() so ....

Answer (score 1):

The child process coutinue fork new child process, you just need stop it .

Like this:

```
 switch (fork()) {

    case -1 : {
            printf("\n\nproblem with fork() !!! \n\n");
            exit(0);
            };

    case 0 : {
             i = 24 ;                 //--- here I set i = 24 , so child process will stop fork new child process.
            WriteOnShared_Mem(ii);
            }break;
    default : {
            ChildPidTab[ii] = p;
            usleep(50000);
            ReadShared_MemMp(nbSect, 24,ChildPidTab);
            };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok if i do like you said, I will have only 1 child ? no ?

Comment: No You did not understood how `fork` works, or you are too novice on plain *C* programming.

Comment: I'm a novice, i started just last year :)

Comment: @shubha You will have 24 child process run the same time\