# Why strange behavior of fork system call?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

```
int main(void) {
    printf("abc");
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code is :

```
abcabc
```

Why is it printing twice, even when fork system call is after the printf statement?

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/pvxBlR)

Comment: BTW, `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>` are missing, and your question is Linux or POSIX specific (e.g. `fork` does not exist on Windows)

Comment: Cross-post: http://jhreview.com/tech-stack/questions/34978568/why-strange-behavior-of-fork-system-call

Comment: Many multi-dups of this:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `stdout`  is buffered, often line-buffered. And in your program the buffer is flushed only at `exit` time, or when returning from `main` (and that happens "twice" when `fork` don't fail).

Try adding `fflush(NULL);` before the `fork();` (which you should almost always do)

BTW, you should always keep the result of `fork` and handle [three cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18549451/841108): `fork` failure, in child, in parent.

So `fork` is behaving as it should, but `printf` has not the naive immediate side-effect you imagine: it is *buffering* so the real output may happen latter. You'll also observe the buffering by replacing `fork()` with `sleep(15)` (the output happening at `exit` time, or at end of `main`, so *after* the `sleep`, and for 15 seconds your program won't apparently output anything)

You might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understanding what system calls are happening...

Comment: The `fork()` copies the whole process, even the buffer containing the unprinted `abc`.  When they both exit, each process flushes its buffer with the unprinted `abc`, and so you see it twice because each process is printing it when it's being flushed.